# How do I accept warning message on SFTP server when trying to connect programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server and get this error message:

> No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (public key,keyboard-interactive).

I believe this is because when I log onto the server using SSH secure shell I get a warning message from the server.  Once I 'OK' this message I can then log in using the Keyboard Interactive Authentication Method.  How do I 'OK' this message programmatically?

This is the code I'm using. Exception fires from `sftp.Connect()`.

```
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod keybAuth = new 
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
keybAuth.AuthenticationPrompt += new 
    EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);


ConnectionInfo coninfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, username, keybAuth);

using(var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(pathRemotefile);

    for each (var file in files)
    {
        using (Stream filestream = File.OpenWrite(pathLocalFile))
        {
            sftp.DownloadFile(pathRemotefile, filestream);
        }
    }

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

PuTTY Event Log

```
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Looking up host "****************" for SSH connection
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Connecting to ***.***.***.*** port 22
2019-08-07 10:40:42 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.72
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
2019-08-07 10:40:42 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Using SSH protocol version 2
2019-08-07 10:40:42 No GSSAPI security context available
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange using 2048-bit modulus and hash SHA-1 (unaccelerated) with a server-supplied group
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Host key fingerprint is:
2019-08-07 10:40:42 ssh-rsa 1024 d6:65:b9:53:c2:d4:54:91:28:5e:7b:b9:de:10:fe:12
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Initialised HMAC-SHA-1 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
2019-08-07 10:40:42 Initialised HMAC-SHA-1 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
2019-08-07 10:40:45 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Access granted
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Opening main session channel
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Opened main channel
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Allocated pty
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Started a shell/command
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Session sent command exit status 1
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Sent EOF message
2019-08-07 10:41:09 Main session channel closed
2019-08-07 10:41:09 All channels closed
```

PuTTY screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is there 3-digit numeric prefix?

Comment: @i486 What do you mean? Don't you mean **FTP** status codes? With is about **SFTP** (though it's actually about **SSH**), not about **FTP**.

Comment: @gnic Is your `HandleKeyEvent` ever called? Did you check? + Show us a verbose output/log file for a successful authentication using any SSH client  (PuTTY or OpenSSh `ssh`).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  No HandleKeyevent is not called, presumably because there is no Authentication prompt but a warning message regarding logging on.  i.e. Use of this computer system is restricted to xxx users etc etc etc   once accepted  the authentication prompt appears.

Comment: There's nothing like a warning message in SSH. Show us the logs I've asked for.

Comment: SSH (secure shell) is a command line login to a remote machine while SFTP (File Transfer protocol) to which is used to upload and down load files.  The error message indicates a certificate is not found for the verification.

Comment: @jdweng *"The error message indicates a certificate is not found for the verification"* - How did you come to that conclusion? The error message is about *authentication*, not about *host key verification* (if that's what you mean by *"certificate"*).

Comment: The key has a public and private component.  The private key is in the certificate.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients

Comment: Private key is not a certificate. The only mention of "certificate" in that wiki article is in *"OpenSSH supports the minimal certificate format since v5.4"* - What refers to proprietary non-standard OpenSSH extension. Standard SSH has no certificates. You are just confusing OP here. OP obviously uses keyboard interactive authentication method. No public/private key and definitely no certificates.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl    This is all I'm getting from a PuTTY log before the remote host closes the connection

=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2019.08.07 09:16:59 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
login as: ***
Use of this computer system is restricted to **** authorized users, who must
comply with the Acceptable Use Policy.  Use and activity may be monitored or
recorded and may be subject to auditing.
 Unauthorized access is strictly prohibited.
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password: 
Last login: Wed Aug  7 04:17:37 2019 from **************

Comment: That's not PuTTY event log. To get PuTTY event log right click PuTTY window title + Add the log into your question, not in comments. + Post also PuTTY 0.72 screenshot.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  log and screenshot added.

Comment: I do not think that's PuTTY 0.72. + Can you also post a screenshot of the message, where you have to click "OK"?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl   Log edited to PuTTY 0.72.  I only get the message prompt from SSH Secure shell application which was normally used by client.  This is would be the Pre-Authentication banner described in Putty 0.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "warning" message which you describe in an SSH authentication banner.

The banner is by default ignored by SSH.NET. Unless you handle `Session.UserAuthenticationBannerReceived` or `ConnectionInfo.AuthenticationBanner`. And even if you handle it (incorrectly), you would never get the *"No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication"*.

---

Your actual problem is that while you set up `KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod`, you never use it, as your `coninfo` is never used in your code.

This should work:

```
var sftp = new SftpClient(coninfo)
```